# File Hashing using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hash, gruntjs, requirejs

I am currently working on a Angualar JS project based on angularAMD.

Link: http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/#/home

Here we include only the necessary dependent files in needed by the controllers and not all the files.

eg.

```
define(['angularAMD', 'common/services/service1', 'module1/services/service2',], function (angularAMD) {
    'use strict';

    angularAMD.controller('abcController', function ($scope, service1, service2) {

              // controller code goes here 
    }
```

I have tried **Grunt Hashing** but
Grunt provides hashing but the location of the hashed files changes.

This does not change the path of the files inside individual controller as a result the application fails to run. i.e `service1, service2`

**Question**
I was wondering if there was a way to hash the files when we include a new files?

Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please share the source for service1 & service2

Comment: @steve service 1 and service 2 I guess just to put a problem this can be any js file which is getting used by controller.

Comment: My thought is that service1 & 2 files are not setup properly; i.e. they aren't setup using define or not registering their individual providers properly to be looked up by the controller

Comment: can you post your GruntFile?

Answer (score 2):

how do u set up your modules. Your main.js may look like this

```
'use strict';
require.config({
    waitSeconds: 0,
    urlArgs: "bust=v1.0.0",
    paths: {
        bootstrap: 'Scripts/bootstrap.min',
        jquery: 'Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min',
        angular: 'Scripts/angular.min',
        angularRoute: 'Scripts/angular-route.min',
        angularAMD: 'Scripts/angularAMD.min',
        app: 'ngApp/app',
        appConfig: 'ngApp/app.config',

        /*register Services - Start*/
        service1: 'ngServices/Common/service1',
        service2: 'ngServices/module/service2',
        /*register Services - End*/

        /*register Filters - Start*/

        /*register Filters - End*/

        /*register Controllers - Start*/

        /*register Controllers - End*/



    },

    // specifying library dependencies
    shim: {
        'bootstrap':{ deps:['jquery']},
        'angular': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: 'angular' },
        'angularRoute': { deps: ['angular'] },
        'angularAMD': { deps: ['angular'] }
    },

    // define application bootstrap
    deps: ['app']
});
```

and in your index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="appController as appCtrl" ng-cloak>
        <div >
                <ng-view></ng-view>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script data-main="main" src="Scripts/require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and in your controllers

```
'use strict';
define(['angularAMD', 'service1', 'service2'],
function (angularAMD) {

    angularAMD.controller('abcController', ['service1', 'service2',
    function (service1, service1) {
        var self = this,
         // your code
    }]);
});
```

Comment: but then the idea of loading file based on a module will not make sense. since including service1 and service2 in main.js will load the file.

service1: 'ngServices/Common/service1',
service2: 'ngServices/module/service2',

Comment: @Abhimanyu. No, it will load dynamically. we are specifying the path for service1 or service2 in the main.js. The file will load only when we define['service1'..] by angularAMD'

Comment: oh yes missed the point, but in a large project, setting all file path in main.js make sense?, since it will pollute  main.js, do we have any other idea for that.

Comment: Yes, of course. in a large application , it will be easy to maintain the path in a single file rather than specifying the path names in all the modules

Comment: Ciril, how can we use versioning of file using above structure(hashing of files) and I want to combine all files into single file. here is my requrejs grunt task https://jsfiddle.net/jgm4u8ok/

Comment: If you combining all the files in to one, i dont think there is a  significance of using AngularAMD and lazy loading.

Comment: Could you please add urlArgs=v1.0 in the main.js file. I have modified the answer. It will append v1.0 to your files. So we could avoid cache bursting

Comment: Ciril, 2 things can this urlArgs can be a md5 value, 2- how to do versioning for HTML file. I am referring my HTML file like below in app.js or directive. .when('/abc/list', angularAMD.route({ templateUrl: assets.html_abc_list, title: 'abc List', controller: 'abcContoller', controllerUrl: 'abc-list-controller', showHeader: true, resolve: { header:unction () {}}))

Comment: As of RequireJS 2.2.0, urlArgs can be a function. If a function, it will receive the module ID and the URL as parameters, and it should return a string that will be added to the end of the URL. Return an empty string if no args. requirejs.config({
    urlArgs: function(id, url) {
        var args = 'v=1';
        return args;
    }
});

Comment: Okie Ciril, how to do HTML file versioning which I asked in my previous comment.

Comment: html files are not loading through require.js. so we need to do some other stuffs to handle this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122089/discussion-between-abhimanyu-and-ciril-sebastian).